# Does scheduleAtFixedRate has to be called again if exception is correctly caught?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to schedule a Thread at a specific time of the day, e.g. 4 AM, every day, rescheduling even after an exception is caught.

I had a Thread scheduled on application startup rescheduling himself with a simple ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(new ThreadItself) at the end of its execution. But I need to specify the initial delay for the thread. I knew about scheduleAtFixedDelay/Rate, but as of documentation it does stop next executions of the thread if there is an exception.

I had this

Inside MyScheduler

```java
public class MyScheduler{


   public void init(){
      ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor myScheduledThreadPoolExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
      myScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(new MyThread(), delay, TimeUnit.HOURS);
   }

   public void scheduleNextMyThread(int delay){
      myScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(new MyThread(), delay, TimeUnit.HOURS);
   }

}
```

Inside the thread

```java
public class MyThread extends Thread {

private MyScheduler myScheduler;

public MyThread(Thread scheduler) {
   this.myScheduler = scheduler;
}

@Override
public void run() {
   try {
      // Try Work
   } catch (Exception exc) {
      // Catch Exception
   } finally {
      // Reschedule myself
      myScheduler.scheduleNextMyThread(delay);
   }
}

}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to reschedule MyThread at a specific time using scheduleAtFixedRate() to set the initial delay and reschedule itself.

I ended up writing this

```java
Inside MyScheduler

myScheduledThreadPoolExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

public void scheduleMyThreadAtFixedRate(int delay){

   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
   cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DATE)+1, 4, 0, 0);
   myScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyThread(), initialDelay, delay, TimeUnit.HOURS);

}
```

Inside MyThread

```java
public class MyThread extends Thread {

private Scheduler scheduler;

public MyThread(Thread scheduler) {
   this.scheduler = scheduler;
}

@Override
public void run() {
   try {
      // Try Work
   } catch (Exception exc) {
      // Catch Exception
      // HERE IS MY DOUBT. IS THIS NECESSARY?
      myScheduler.scheduleMyThreadAtFixedRate(delay);
   } 
}

}
```

So... Exception is caught. Is it necessary to reschedule MyThread again inside the catch block or since the exceptions are not thrown it continues its normal scheduling?

Comment: Sounds like something you could just test in 5 seconds, did you? Its maybe also covered in the Javadoc of that class and method.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.
I abandoned this approach for now and left things unchanged has I had in the beginning. Documentation does not cover specific behavior in my case, or i was not able to find it. I was looking for someone who knew JVM enough to explain what happpens down there too.